# Сформировать UPDATE в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Вопрос проще понять, если сразу взглянуть на код

```
static int Reset()
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        return db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Employees SET StatusCode=0 WHERE StatusCode>0");
    }
}
```

Можно ли средствами EF сформировать запрос на обновление (одним запросом, а не сначала прочитать в память, изменить и вызывать `db.SaveChanges()` - считаю это крайне неэффективным), или использовать `ExecuteSqlCommand()` в таких случаях - единственное решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите пакет `EntityFramework.Extended` - кажется, он делает именно то что вам нужно.

Но надо отметить, что "пакетные" операции не дружат с кешем контекста - то есть возможен конфликт при сохранении если сначала обновить запись пакетной операцией а потом попытаться сохранить ее же обычным способом. Используйте пакетные операции если знаете что делаете.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, только как вы уже написали, через обычный SQL запрос. Entity Framework на то и Entity, что работает с сущностями. Без получения сущности ничего не получится. Но не забудьте потом обновить ваши данные в программе. Тогда у вас тоже получится 2 запроса.

Comment: _Но не забудьте потом обновить ваши данные в программе. Тогда у вас тоже получится 2 запроса_ - можно подробнее про второй запрос? не очень понял

Comment: @Qutrix Вы обновили в базе данных объекты. Если вы хотите дальше использовать их в программе, вам придется их запрашивать. А так они у вас уже были бы обновлены в программе. Конечно, если вы их не будете больше использовать, то SQL запрос предпочтительнее.

Comment: Если запрос не очень сложный и данных не так много - думаю быстрее изменить данные в самой программе

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще нашел способ для кейсов, когда знаешь id удаляемого объекта

```
var toDelete = new Destination { DestinationId = 2 };
context.Destinations.Attach(toDelete);
context.Destinations.Remove(toDelete);
context.SaveChanges();
```